# Eclipse android ADT installation issue

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I followed every step to install android ADT plugin installation with Eclipse IDE.

I have Eclipse for Java installed on my windows 7 machine.

I followed each and every step. Despite of doing all I am getting the following error. Nobody had this error. I am so anxious please help

```
An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
The file "E:\andrioid\eclipse\plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_17.0.0.v201203161636-291853.jar" does not exist
```

Comment: try downloading the missing file and past it manually..

Comment: With a very similar error it worked for me to **first** install the `Developer Tools -> Android Development Tools`, restart, and then the rest (DDMS, Hierarchy Viewer, etc.)

Comment: @ExceptionSlayer: No worries, good to hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Download it manually in temp folder.
- Choose Help -> Install New Software, in Eclipse menu
- Click Add button
- Point to downloaded file
- Restart and enjoy ;)

welcome to android wonderland ;)

Comment: This didn't work for me; when I tried installing from local archive I got the same error the OP did. What did work was installing just the "Android Development Tools" component, then restarting Eclipse and installing the rest of the components.

Comment: What was the error actually? "file doesn't exist" when you pointed to downloaded zip file?! o.O

Comment: No, the error was not "file doesn't exist". I got the same error when trying to install from local archive that I got while trying to install from site. Note that @bossi has comment beneath the question indicating a similar experience.

Answer (score 2):

```
You see this error because 
When you install ADT plugins you select ADT-17.x.x.zip folder of ADT is higher version but you have install that plugins. 

goto> Window>Preferences>Install/Update>Unistall or Update> installed software

  Android DDMS  
  Android Development Tools 
  Android Hierarchy Viewer      
  Android Traceview 

select all this things and click on update

Hope it will works .

Thanks
```

Comment: if you have .zip eclipse software then delete currently unzip eclipse software and then unzip eclipse from your .zip file and again install sdk and plungins

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow all steps..
1. Help
2.Install new Software
3. Add
4.Select archive file from your Location.
5.then select on Developer tools(which contain 4 file)
6.restart your Eclipse.
Then Press Next....
Your Plugin is ready....

**Note** while installing plugin internet is necessary to install this.