# Error when installing Android ADT on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am trying to install the android ADT for Eclipse from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

And get the following error:

[image]

If it helps, I am running windows 8.1 and using the latest version of Eclipse. Thank you.

Comment: This may be helpfull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989267/eclipse-android-adt-installation-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the Icon of your Dialog I see that you are running Eclipse 4.4. Unfortunately, Android ADT doesn't seem to be supported by that version. Check out this thread as well: [Google adt/gwt support for eclipse 4.4 (Luna)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431005/google-adt-gwt-support-for-eclipse-4-4-luna)

Comment: Installing for Eclipse 4.4(Luna) I am still getting the same error message during the installation?

Comment: ? As I wrote, 4.4 does not seem to be supported. As an alternative you might use the Eclipse ADT bundle which can be obtained from [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).